# django display message after POST form submit

Tags: django, forms, post, message

I have a page with a POST form, that have a action set to some url.
i.e assume this page url is `/form_url/` :
    
    ..

The view in `/submit_url/` take care of the form data. After this, I want to return the same page of the form with a success message.
In the view that take care for the POST form, I use `HttpResponseRedirect`, in order to "clear" the form data from the browser.
But in this way I can't display a message in the form page, unless I do something like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/form_url/?success=1")
```

and then check for this parameter in the template. I don't like this way, since if the user refreshes the page, he will still see the success message.

I've noticed that in django admin site, the delete/add of objects does use redirect after POST submit, and still display a success message somehow. 
How?

I've already briefly seen django "messaging" app, but I want to know how it work first..

Answer (score 72):

The django admin uses `django.contrib.messages`, you use it like this:

In your view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def my_view(request):
    ...
       if form.is_valid():
          ....
          messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
```

And in your templates:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li  {% if message.tags %} class=" {{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 12):

For Class Based Views use self.request

I also use self.request.path_info in my return

```
from django.contrib import messages

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    ...
       def form_valid(self, form):
          ....
          self.object.save()

          messages.success(self.request, 'Form submission successful')
          
          return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

Same template as damio's answer:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li  {% if message.tags %} class=" {{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView 
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    success_url = '/success/'
    success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do a redirect to clear the form data. All you need to do is re-instantiate the form:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None)
    success = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = YourForm()
            success = True
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form})
```

If the user refreshes the page, they're going to initiate a GET request, and `success` will be `False`. Either way, the form will be unbound on a GET, or on a successful POST.

If you leverage the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/), you'll still need to add a conditional in the template to display the messages if they exist or not.

Comment: If I use render() to return a response from a view which is requsted by POST, then if the user refreshes the page the browser will prompt a popup if to send the form again. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You really don't have much of a choice here. You either need to issue a redirect and pass the querystring parameter, or you need to use a message/session value.

Comment: Does the django message app clear the session data after it is used ? Since there is no need to save the session after I display it.

Comment: Yes. Each message is only shown once per request cycle.

Answer (score 5):

Django messages framework stores the messages in the session or cookie (it depends on the [storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#storage-backends)).

Comment: I see. I thought so. I'm trying to do this without using the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a classed based view with django forms, and granted you've got the messages.html template set up, you can simply pass the 'SuccessMessageMixin' into your view like below

```
class YourView(SuccessMessageMixin,View):
        success_message = 'your message_here'
```

This will display your message upon form success